# How can I change the following command for multipe tar.gz compressed files?

Tags: awk

`awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$3; next } ($3) in a { print $0 }' input1.txt input2.txt`

The command working fine with normal file. I need to change the command for multiple compressed 'input2.txt.tar.gz' files.

Comment: extract your file first and then use awk, for example `tar -xvf input1.txt.tar.gz -C /tmp/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract your file first and then use `awk`, for example

```
tar -xvf input1.txt.tar.gz -C /tmp/
tar -xvf input2.txt.tar.gz -C /tmp/
```

So your `/tmp` directory will have 2 files extracted

and then

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$3; next }$3 in a' /tmp/input1.txt /tmp/input2.txt
```

--edit--

> I mean the compressed files without extract to any temporary folder

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]=$3; next }
     $3 in a
     ' <(tar --to-stdout -xf input1.tar.gz) <(tar --to-stdout -xf input2.tar.gz)
```

> **man tar**

```
   -O, --to-stdout
          extract files to standard output
```

You can also use `<(tar -O -xf input1.tar.gz) <(tar -O -xf input2.tar.gz)`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i need without extraction in any sub folder because the file size is too big

Comment: I didn't get you please explain

Comment: I mean the compressed files without extract to any temporary folder